# Way to integrate a latex-based wiki into a drupal 6 site

Tags: files

I have a website with users already designed in Drupal 6. We would like to add an area/module that would allow registered users of a certain type/category to be able to collectively edit/contribute to a set of wiki-based statistical documents, ideally written in LaTeX, but that other users (registered and anonymous) could download in the original LaTeX or exported to .pdf. (Imagine a wiki-based, open-source statistics textbook.) There are wiki modules and LaTeX modules for Drupal, but no LaTeX-wiki modules.

Is there some stand-alone wiki software that could be hosted on a sub-domain of our site but uses the Drupal user permissions to manage access? Is there a Drupal module or option I haven't found?

What we have:
Drupal 6 site that anyone can visit/see, but that requires registered user status to contribute/participate on site. We can add subdomains/create any databases, etc. needed on the servers to do what we need to do.

What we envision: 
A wiki that allows a subset of registered users to collaboratively edit/write statistical texts easily (many of these users are already familiar with LaTeX) that will preserve mathematical equations and render them onscreen (.html) and as .pdf output.

Version tracking and attribution to particular users is necessary.

Any user can view .html of current wiki, or download the raw LaTeX file (for their own use), or choose certain wiki pages to be exported as .pdf.

Is there some stand-alone wiki software that would meet these criteria? And, if so, could we somehow use the same user database as our drupal install to set permissions? We anticipate hiring someone to do the programming necessary (our current Drupal developers do not do this level of development), but it would be helpful to know whether we're looking for someone to modify two existing tools to work together or to write a new drupal module that suits our needs.

Answer (score 2):

A solution would be to have a Drupal based wiki on your website and then to allow the usage of LaTeX markup for the wiki content. DruTeX][1](http://drupal.org/project/drutex) may allow the later, while [Wikitools](http://drupal.org/project/wikitools) should provide the former. They will both need to be properly configured.